# How to redirect to home page after sign out in a Blazor serverside application

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side

My Blazor server-side application is authenticated using Azure B2C. After signing out, the user is redirected to a generic page that informs that sign out was successful. How can I make the app redirect to the home page (i.e. login page) instead?

Here is a part of my authentication:

```
<AuthorizeView>
<Authorized>
    @if (canEditProfile)
    {
        <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/EditProfile" style="color: white">Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</a>
    }
    else
    {
        <span style="color: white">Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</span>
    }
    <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut" style="color: white">Log out</a>
</Authorized>
<NotAuthorized>
    <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn" style="color: white">Log in</a>
</NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Comment: are you using MSAL?

Comment: @JuanmaFeliu Yes, I do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions> (OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = async context =>
                {
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri);
                    context.HandleResponse();
                };

            });
```

This is based on an old issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18865).

Answer (score 0):

In the logout request, send a `post_logout_redirect_uri`

**post_logout_redirect_uri**: *The URL that the user should be redirected to after successful sign out. If it isn't included, Azure AD B2C shows the user a generic message. Unless you provide an id_token_hint, you should not register this URL as a reply URL in your Azure AD B2C application settings.*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-a-sign-out-request

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please give me a little sample? I can't find where/how I can set this post_logout_redirect_uri to point to the home page.

Comment: GET https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms%2F

Comment: @JuanmaFeliu Thanks, but I don't see how this can be applied within my Blazor Server-side application. Where should this be placed?

Comment: This doc can help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-microsoft-accounts?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: No, ASP .Net core wasm.

Comment: @JuanmaFeliu So the title of the article is wrong? 
Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly standalone app with Microsoft Accounts