# navigate to the sign-in page after the user log out with blazor and Azure

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side

I am trying to use the Azure Active Directory to authorize my blazor server app. I managed to successfully use it but I want when the user logs out. it shall navigate him to the sign-in page. how to do that?
My configuration for Blazor project
[image: Blazor app settings]

[image: Blazor Login View]

[image: Azure AD Application configration]

when the use click log-out it navigates him to this page

[image: Logout page]

then how to navigate to the sign-in page again after the user log out?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Blazor Server App and enabled Authentication Type as `Microsoft Identity platform`.

[image]

- When Configured with Identity platform, the code will be autogenerated.

[image]

***Redirect URI:***

The only change I found in `appsettings.json` compared to your config file is, I also have `TenantID` included in the settings.

- Iam able to get the Login page after clicking on the Logout Page with the default code.

[image]

- On clicking `LogOut`, the below page is displayed.

[image]

***Properties in UserFlow:***

[image]

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-a-sign-out-request),  `post_logout_redirect_uri`   can be used to redirect to any URL after sign-out.

Also refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68022728/how-to-redirect-to-home-page-after-sign-out-in-a-blazor-serverside-application) which explains the same for more details.